# Id's in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a user model and a address model. How do I have the address form to include the id of the user id. (i.e my address model has a id and a id_user)?

Answer (score 1):

Your address model should contain a `user_id` field, not a `id_user` field. It seems like you're just getting started with Rails, so I would recommend reading the official [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and [Association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guides to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into record associations. I strongly recommend [the guide on that very subject on the Rails website](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Since you took the time of creating two separate models (one for users and one for addresses) I figure it's because you can have one or more adresse per user. [So I would recommend using a has_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association)

In your migration file for your address model you should have a column name `user_id` of type `integer`. By convention, rails will use columns named `model_id` for an association with a model. So in your case, the model `user` can be linked with an address through the column `user_id`.

Having the column is not enough however. You also need to tell Rails about the association in the model. So add the following to the top of your user model (app/model/user.rb I would presume)

```
has_many :addresses
```

Then, tell your address model it belongs to a user. Doing so is again very straight forward. Add the following at the top of your address model (app/model/address.rb)

```
belongs_to :user
```

From there, you can do all sort of wonderful things. To create your forms, you may want to look at Nested model forms. There's two Railscast on it [Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

As your experience with Rails seems limited at the time. I'd recommend also looking into the [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), looking at the series of tutorial from Envy Labs (comically named [Rails for Zombies](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies)) and when you get rolling browse through the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) by Ryans Bates